# Reliably Extracting String In Flutter List Every Time

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a quite interesting exercise I've been trying to solve for a while now, but haven't come up with a reliable solution, so I thought you guys could help me out. I have this String that is composed of few random custom parts, for example:

```
"William\nWilliam description here...\n$170.00 usd") + Uuid().v4();
```

I need to extract the part after '$' and '.', in this case 170, but it can be any number between.

**UPDATE**

as I said in the last comment, if I wanted to do it in a function (find the price only), it could go something like this:

```
deleteSumItem(item) {
final regEx = RegExp(r'\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?');
const textToSearch = r'item';
final priceValueMatch = regEx.firstMatch(textToSearch);
print(priceValueMatch.group(0));
_totalPrice.remove(priceValueMatch);
_counter = _counter - priceValueMatch; //getting error here to convert to num
  //but int.parse won't work either, then I get the String error
  //RegExp can't be assigned to paremeter String

}
```

Also, this function returns null for regex, so there is some mistake I'm making, any thoughts?

```
deleteSumItem(item) {
final regEx = RegExp(r'\1\d+(?:\.\d+)?');
final priceValueMatch = regEx.firstMatch(r'item');
print('THIS IS REGEX: $priceValueMatch');} //priceValueMatch returns null
```

**fix**

```
deleteSumItem(item) {
RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'\^(\d+)\^');
String input = item;
String match = regExp.firstMatch("r" + '"' + input + '"').group(1);
print('Match: $match');
int number = int.parse(match);
print('Number: $number');

_totalPrice.remove(number);
_counter = _counter - number;}
```

Comment: Maybe extract 3 or 4 digits that are before '' **.00**'' would work, how would that go?

Comment: Can you always count on the line breaks `\n` always being there?  Also, will the dollar sign always be there?  Is it always $xxx.xx format?  And when I saw 'always' in these questions, I mean ALWAYS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can answer 'yes' to the questions in my above comment, you can simply use regular expressions to find the price value in your string:

```
final regEx = RegExp(r'\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?');
const textToSearch = r'William\nWilliam description here...\n$170.00 cm';
final priceValueMatch = regEx.firstMatch(textToSearch);
print(priceValueMatch.group(0)); // this will print $170.00
```

The regular expression is looking for a dollar sign `\$` followed by 1 or more digits `d+` followed by optional decimal point and optional digits behind that decimal `(?:\.\d+)?`.

This actually ignores a lot of the questions in my above comment.  This simply looks for a price value preceded by a dollar sign within the string you give it.

Here is another approach based on your comments.  *This is assuming the new line characters will always exist*

```
const textToSearch = 'William\nWilliam description here...\n170.00 cm';
final lines = textToSearch.split('\n'); // Split on new line character
// If your template is always the same,
// then your number will be at the start of line 3:
print(lines[2]); // Will print: 170.00 cm
// If you want just your 170 value then:
final regEx = RegExp(r'\d+'); 
final priceValueMatch = regEx.firstMatch(lines[2]);
final priceInt = int.parse(priceValueMatch.group(0));
print(priceInt); // Will print: 170
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was out. Basically I can say **yes** to all the questions since it is a template. The only thing I would want to change for final value there is that I wouldn't need `$170.00`, but `170` or any other theoretical number on there, so it could go on a list of ints. I notice I made the mistake there, since `$` shouldn't be there, instead I could put any other sign for recognition.

Comment: But I suppose then the Regex would be something like`(r'\**some sign**\d+(?:\**some sign**\d+)?')` if I maybe instead of the `$` and `.` added some other sign to easier recognize the string.

Comment: Or it could be done in a function, but it says that it can't be assigned to num, even when I do int.parse(), updated the main post with the function.

Comment: @arbiter - I've updated my answer based on your comments.  It's a similar but different approach, utilizing the line breaks in your template.  I also removed the dollar sign as that didn't sound like it was supposed to be there.

Comment: Yep, got it to work, I appreciate your comments, I will mark it complete. I also added my solution with your help to main code in case someone else has a similar puzzle.